# How to get function names from profile addresses?

Tags: linux, gnu, profiler, addr2line

I am putting together a performance profiler in Linux and I am having trouble mapping the collected stack trace information to function names.

I am currently calling addr2line as follows from my post processing code

```
  FILE* pipe = popen("addr2line -f -i -s -C -e <libname> <address>", "r");
  if (!pipe) return;

  const size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
  string result;
  while (!feof(pipe))
  {
    if (fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, pipe) != NULL)
    result += buffer;
  }

  pclose(pipe);
```

However, this is terribly slow as my profile has a lot of samples. Is there any other utility like addr2line that is faster or can I call addr2line in a more efficient way than I am doing?

Answer (score 1):

I got past this problem by modifying the source code of the addr2line utility and converted it into a library. So I am now loading this library into my profile analyzer and calling 'addr2line' as if it were a function!

Comment: Nice idea. Mind sharing the code or instructions? Would be very helpful to me and maybe others.